# How to restore Windows 8 UEFI after deleting Ubuntu Partition?

Tags: uninstall, windows-8, uefi

I bought a Fujitsu with pre-installed Windows 8. I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu as I had done on my previous Windows 7 laptop. I followed some guides and managed to install it, with the GRUB boot manager (using boot repair).

However I have decided to sell the laptop and needed to remove Ubuntu, I followed some guide which told me to delete the partition in Windows, then use the Recovery disk to restore the Windows boot manager. It didn't work. I am now left with a laptop I need to fix in 48 hours and no clue how to do it.

I tried re-installing Ubuntu but after restarting it still loads up grub recovery.

How do I restore the Windows boot manager? I  have seen some guides but people say things like mount ESP - but don't explain how to do it - I don't have a clue how!

Comment: Related generic question about removing Ubuntu and reinstalling Windows: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/114818)... However, things might be different for pre-installed Windows 8...

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it, I deleted the EFI partition and the C partition. Then created a 1gb partition for EFI and just installed windows from fresh! (Using the install option on Windows 8 Recovery)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact problem. I looked around for a technical solution, but suprisingly, the built-in Windows 8 "Reset your PC" functionality did the trick.

http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-restore-and-reset-windows-8-to-factory-settings/

I ran "Reset your PC", which replaced the Grub bootloader with the original. Created a new user account and used the Windows 8 built-in partition manager to remove the prior Ubuntu partition. Worked without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recovery option.

Turn on your laptop, and press <kbd>F12</kbd> to get the Boot Menu.  Highlight `Recovery and Utility`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

OR

Click the `MyRecovery` icon on your windows desktop.