# Grub installed in pendrive, how to boot from HDD?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I've installed Ubuntu into a pendrive and now I can't boot into windows without the pen plugged in. It seems that this question ([I need my pendrive to boot into Ubuntu, how to correct this and boot from the HDD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367339/i-need-my-pendrive-to-boot-into-ubuntu-how-to-correct-this-and-boot-from-the-hd)) has already the solution, but I need help finding out what partition I should use.

My partitions looks like this:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System" UUID="F290E90290E8CDE3" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="TI30925800A" UUID="DE6E0DDF6E0DB0F7" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda4: LABEL="HDDRECOVERY" UUID="0CA84EB2A84E9A5A" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="605E653B5E650ADC" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="7cba5674-27f1-474d-9678-896e46d84c5e" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc5: UUID="9500fb35-af38-4272-8475-74a9ee465329" TYPE="swap"
```

sda1/sda2/sda3 have windows installed, sdb1 it's probably the the 32g SSD disk that helps windows hibernation times, and sdc1 and sdc5 it's probably the ubuntu pen

Should I use the `dev/sda1`, which is probably the window boot partition?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu only to the pendrive (no Ubuntu on the HDD), then there is no need to follow that other question's answer, because if you only have windows on your computer you don't need grub at all.

Just use your Windows install DVD, boot from that one, and repair the bootsector. If you don't know how to do that just read the beginning of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/143482/221281).

Comment: I've already tried that, with no success. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/394992/removing-grub-restoring-windows-bootloader

Comment: @Filipe Then it is a problem with windows and you should contact microsoft support or go to a windows forum. (My last guess is you may try the answers [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/283596/how-to-restore-windows-8-uefi-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition))